# A few problems on series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The following are two series problems which I couldn't do any help would be appreciated

1) Find a series $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n $
 of positive terms such that  $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n $ diverges and $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n^2 $= $10^{-133}$

2) Find a series $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n $
 of positive terms such that  $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n $ = $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n^2 $= 7

Answer (score 2):

For 1), we know that $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges (let converges to $A>0$). Then just take $a_n=\sqrt{\frac{10^{-133}}{A}}\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Fot 2) take $a_n=\lambda\,r^n$ with $\lambda>0$ and $0<r<1$. Then, using the formula for the sum of a geometric series,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=\frac{\lambda}{1-r}=7,\quad \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n^2=\frac{\lambda^2}{1-r^2}=t.
$$
Solve for $\lambda$ and $r$.

Answer (score 0):

1)Do you know a series $\sum a_n$ which diverges and $\sum a_n^2=a$ converges? If yes, consider the sequence $b_0=\sqrt{10^{-133}-a}$, $b_{n+1}=a_n$ (be careful. Maybe $10^{-133}<a$).

2) If $a_n=\frac1{2^n}$ then $\sum a_n=2$ and $\sum a_n^2=\frac43$. Find $x,y>0$ such that if $b_0=x,b_1=y, b_{n+2}=a_n$ then $\sum b_n=\sum b_n^2=7$ (τhe positive solution of $x^2-x-\frac13$ will do. Why?).